# How to monitor a SAN server (via iSCSI)?

Tags: windows, monitoring, storage-area-network, iscsi

What options do I have to monitor a SAN server that provides iSCSI storage to a network for availability and performance? (Windows options preferred)

Comment: That depends upon the system that your iSCSI server is running...

Comment: To clarify: I do not want to monitor the system itself (through SNMP et al.), I want to monitor the iSCSI "ports".

Answer (score 1):

More information would help (the type of SAN server, specifically), but have you considered looking at SNMP traps with something like Nagios or Cacti?